# Error #1009: in flash project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am getting this error-

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.  at final_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()

Most of my project works perfectly still - but the one part that loads photos doesnt do anything when the button is pressed.  My code -

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

stop();

function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Home");
}
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);

function goAbout (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("About");
}
about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goAbout);

function goWhat (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("What");
}
what_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goWhat);

function goHow (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("How");
}
how_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHow);

function goPricing (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Pricing");
}
price_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPricing);

function goContact (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Contact");
}
contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goContact);



play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay)

var images = new Array();

images[0] = "1.png";
images[1] = "2.png";
images[2] = "3.png";
images[3] = "4.png";
images[4] = "5.png";

var currentImage:int = 0;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 0); // 5 seconds
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, switchPics);

function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) {
   myTimer.start();
}

function switchPics(event:TimerEvent):void {
   currentImage = (currentImage+1)%images.length;
   loadWindow.source = images[currentImage];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
}
```

Comment: What is loadWindow? Is it declared on stage?

Comment: Its a UIloader and yes it is on the stage with that instance name

Comment: Updated my answer. Are you sure that the UILoader exists on the frame you are starting the script from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED

```
var images : Array = new Array();
    images.push("1.png");
    images.push("2.png");
    images.push("3.png");
    images.push("4.png");
    images.push("5.png");
```

---

Are you sure that the UILoader exists on the frame you are starting the script from? I tested everything but the buttons and it works fine. I think that the UILoader (loadWindow) does not exist on the frame you are currently at when you trigger the function **switchPics**.

---

Everything looks fine if loadWindow exists.

My guess:

- loadWindow is not declared
- loadwindow is not created
- loadwindow does not accept source parameter/setter

Comment: The button that triggers switchPics is on the same frame as the loadWindow.  Thats why it makes no sense to me, it should work!

Comment: What happens if you trigger it directly without the button? Just run goPlay(null) and see what happens. Works for me.

Comment: If you debug the movie ... what line do you get a crash on?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at final_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[final_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:40]

Comment: Line 40? And what line is line 40 in your file?

Comment: line 40 is var images = new Array();

Comment: var images : Array = new Array();

Comment: try changing it to a different variable name like imageList. Could be a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a semi-colon at:

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay)

Right before line 40 where you are getting the error

Comment: Is the play_btn instance actually called play_btn? Without the semi-colon the line numbering of the error messages might have been off...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes object hasn't been loaded yet.
This can be solved with:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkLoaded)
function checkLoaded(e:Event){
    if(mc){
        //something
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkLoaded)
    }
}
```

Sometimes the eventlisteners should be removed to solve this problem

**UPDATE**

I test the code and I think that Mattias is right. Look to the frames where you put the UILOADER with instance name loadWindow and try to put then in all frames of your project to test